# how to pass user input as a method?

Tags: python, pandas, methods

I'm trying to prompt a user to input a column name in a pandas dataframe and then use that input to display information about the column.
the code I've tried:

```
df = #initializing dataframe
user_input = input('enter column name')
print(df.user_input.describe())
```

but I got the error:

```
df has no attribute user_input
```

assuming that user input is actually valid column name, how can I use the input in such a way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`pandas` lets you lookup a column as an attribute reference if it meets python's syntax rules and doesn't interfere with an existing attribute on the object. In your case, `pandas` would look for a column literally named "user_input".

The more general way to lookup a column is with indexing. It does not have the same constraints. So,

```
f = #initializing dataframe
user_input = input('enter column name')
print(df[user_input].describe())
```

Now `pandas` will use the string entered by the user to look up the column.

One rule[1] of programming is that there should only be one "right way" of doing things. That's obviously not the case for pandas or python in general. But organizations may define what they consider "right". Since attribute lookup of columns only works sometimes, should it be used at all? Debatable!

[1]: *The code is more what you'd call 'guidelines' than actual rules.* -Hector Barbossa, Captain of the Black Perl.

Comment: what rule is that there should be 1 and only 1 right way of doing things? Which programming is that? Perl programmers are not programmers? What are they doing?

Comment: @Hanselmann - [PEP 20 - The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): _There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it._ Column lookup by attribute doesn't cover all cases and its common to end up with a mix of column verses index lookup - ugly! Similar thing with `map` - its only useful in edge condtions, use a comprehension. Assigning a lambda to a variable `my_fctn = lamba x: x**2` ... do `def my_fctn` instead. A good code review regimen includes a style guide. As for perl... what? I didn't mention perl.

Comment: You said "*One rule of programming*"; isn't that general enough to include Perl?

Comment: @Hanselmann - If I understand you, there shouldn't be style guidelines because there is more than one programming language. That's a strange position to take. Suppose I have a dataframe with columns `"starting", "until", "access mode", "update", 3`. Not all can be attributes. Its not obviousl that "update" can't. And, suppose pandas decides to add an "until" function - now you crash.

Answer (score 2):

You can also access a column with `df[]`. Try:

```py
df[user_input].describe()
```

Another way is to use `getattr()`:

```py
getattr(df, user_input).describe()
```

which I think is quite "unnatural".

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I can't upvote it cause I'm new here.